# HOOK_page_alter in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am trying to append a twig template on every page.
In Drupal 7, we basically append it using `hook_page_alter`

```
function hook_page_alter(&$page) { 
  $page['page_bottom']['devel']= array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#markup' => '<div style="clear:both;">' . theme('TEST') . '</div>',
  ); // add test template on every page at bottom position.
}
```

but in Drupal 8 there is no `hook_page_alter` I think.

How to do this in drupal 8??

Comment: Everything you need is here ;) https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `hook_preprocess_page(&$variables)` in Drupal 8 to alter page content.

Example:

```
function bartik_preprocess_page(&$variables){

   $variables['page']['footer_fourt']['test']= array( 
        '#type' => 'markup', 
        '#markup' => '<div style="clear:both;">hello test</div>', );
   kint($variables['page']['footer_fourt']['test']);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[What happened to hook_page_alter is explained here in the Drupal change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2357755) so in your case you'd probably use hook_page_bottom.

Answer (score -1):

even you can use kint() in the theme just attach your theme in variable

Comment: How will `kint` add content to a page?